# How to pass the scroll event from scrollView to tableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have the following view structure, the root view is `UIScrollView`, `UIScrollView` has two `subViews`, it is a `UIView`, the following is a scrollView, set `contentSize` scrollView for the content view size, I want to be contentOffset.y scrollView view.height when the current sliding event transfer to the following tableView to continue processing, so that tableView and scrollView continue to slide

Comment: Why do you have a `UITableView` inside a `UIScrollView` in the first place? TableView inherits from ScrollView itself. -_- Also by adding a view over TableView, you are blocking touch events to both TableView and ScrollView

Answer (score 1):

You could catch each scroll event from your scroll view using this delegate method

```
- scrollViewDidScroll:
```

and then apply same content offset to the table view.